# Find deepest node(s) of a binary tree

Tags: ruby

I have a height method that able to find the height of Binary tree but not sure how to return the deepest node of a binary tree(multiple nodes if same depth).

```
BinaryNode.new(1,BinaryNode.new(2,leaf,leaf),BinaryNode.new(3,leaf,leaf))
```

where leaf represents empty

the height for this tree is 2 and the deepest nodes are 2,3 (same depth)

```
class BinaryNode 
  include Enumerable
  def initialize(element,lchild,rchild)
    @element, @lchild, @rchild = element, lchild, rchild
  end
  def deepestNode
    if self.nil?
      0
    else
      height1=@lchild.height+1
      height2=@lchild.height+1
    end
      height=[height1,height2].max
      height
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you add some context? It's kind a vague example and it's really not clear what you need. Some inputs with expected outputs should be enough.

Comment: I want to find the deepest node of a binary tree.

Comment: we know nothing of you implementation. If you can provide a more detailed context we may be able to provide a better solution. I can try to give you one but assuming tons of things.

Comment: Thanks,I have a binarynode class that takes three parameters. node,left child and right child. I'stuck on how to find the deepest node. only able to find the height of the tree. I edited the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- The Binary Tree is actually the root node
- child_nodes returns the collection of child nodes as an array

---

```rb
class BinaryNode
  attr_reader :element

  def initialize(element,lchild,rchild)
    @element, @lchild, @rchild = element, lchild, rchild
  end

  def height
    if @lchild.nil? && @rchild.nil?
      return 0
    else
     [@lchild, @rchild].collect {|n| n.nil ? 0 : n.height + 1 }.max      
    end
  end

  def deepest_nodes
    return [self] if self.height == 1

    [@lchild, @rchild].select {|n| !n.nil? && (n.height == self.height - 1)}.collect {|n| n.deepest_nodes}.flatten
  end
end
```

---

Refactor:

```
class BinaryNode
  attr_reader :element

  def initialize(element,lchild,rchild)
    @element, @lchild, @rchild = element, lchild, rchild
  end

  def child_nodes
    [@lchild, @rchild].compact
  end

  def height
    if self.child_nodes.empty?
      return 0
    else
      self.child_nodes.collect {|n| n.height + 1 }.max      
    end
  end

  def deepest_nodes
    return [self] if self.depth == 1

    self.child_nodes.select {|n| n.height == self.height - 1}.collect {|n| n.deepest_nodes}.flatten
  end
end
```

---

Getting the elements:

```
BinaryNode.new(1,BinaryNode.new(2,leaf,leaf),BinaryNode.new(3,leaf,leaf)).deepest_nodes.collect {|n| n.element }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I didn't explain too well. I added an example.

Comment: @John, there you have the example using the l/r childs (given that they can be nil or an instance of BinaryNode)

Comment: Minor nitpick: I would probably rename `depth` to `height`, since the depth of a node is usually its distance from the root.

Comment: @Phrogz recap: you are right. We really need a BinaryTree class to make this behave properly.

Comment: not sure why did the deepest_nodes output memory address when use the above example.#<BinaryNode:0x10cb1c288>#<BinaryNode:0x10cb1bea0>

Comment: I'm returning the object, if you need just the @elements you shoudl create readers for them and collect {|n| n.element } them

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node //structure type
{
    int data;
    struct node *left,*right;
};

from main()
{
    Deepestnode= MaxDepth(root);
}

//return type// function name//
struct node*    MaxDepth (struct node* temp, int depth)
{  
    if(temp->next!=NULL && temp->right!=NULL)
    {
        MaxDepth(temp->left ,depth+1);
        MaxDepth(temp->right,depth+1);
    }
    else if(temp->left==NULL && temp->right!=NULL)
        MaxDepth(temp->right,depth+1);
    else if(temp->left!=NULL && temp->right==NULL)
        MaxDepth(temp->left,depth+1);

    else // temp->left==NULL &&temp->right==NULL   
    {
        if(max<depth)
        {
           max=depth;
           Deepestnode=temp;
        }
        return(Deepestnode);
     }
}
```